# How to hide specific element of class and show other elements of same class using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide a line from webpage(shopify product page).
I am using an app but don't have access to its code.
Just want to hide the line- "Powered by App"
I tried hiding the class using css but in the same class there is a H2 heading names-"Customer Reviews" which i want to be shown.

I am attaching the code which i get using inspect element in chrome for that page.

I tried hiding the class using css but in the same class there is a H2 heading names-"Customer Reviews" which i want to be shown.

```
<div class="wc_review_top_title wc_wf_cls" data-bind=“product_name_xyz”>
<h2>Customer Reviews</h2>
<a href=“some_url_link_which_i_cant_show_here” target="_blank" style="display: inline-block !important; float: right !important; font-size: 14px !important; opacity: 1 !important; visibility: visible !important; margin-top: 7px !important; color: #000 !important;">Powered by App</a>
</div>
```

if someone has any idea what would be the css code to hide only element tag "a" and show tag "h2" from same class then please let me know.

Comment: Since the necessary styles are marked as **inline** and **`!important`**, you will need javascript to overwrite them. Those styles are there for a specific reason...so you **can't** hide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `text-indent`

```
.wc_review_top_title a{
  text-indent:-9999em;
}
```

Comment: Nice piece of thinking.... absolute positioning / transform would work too.

Answer (score -2):

You have to delete the following in the a element under style:

```
visibility: visible !important;
```

And add the part to the h2 element to keep it visible

If you can't access it, you have to try changing the color to make it invisible.

However, these themes are built in a way that it is not possible to delete links.